# Is the converse of $ R \cong R^{op} $ true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

If R is commutative, then trivially $R \cong R^{op} $. Is the converse true ?

I understand that for every ring R we can define the opposite ring  $R^{op}$ by reversing the multiplication in R. Given the multiplication * in R, the multiplication ° in $R^{op}$ is defined as $a°b = b*a$. The "identity map" from R to $R^{op}$ , mapping each element to itself, is an isomorphism if and only if R is commutative.

Comment: Are you asking if $R\cong R^{op}$ implies that $R$ is commutative?

Comment: You say it exactly right: the *identity map* is an isomorphism between $R$ and $R^{op}$ if and only if R is commutative, but for both commutative and non-commutative rings there *may* be other isomorphisms

Comment: No, my question is: can we say that $R^{op} \cong R$ is true if R is commutative?

Comment: Then yes. You can say that. The identity map is an isomorphism.

Comment: @Arianita: you already answered that question in the first sentence of your text!

Answer (score 11):

No. A nice example is the [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) $\mathbb{H}$, which are noncommutative but have an involution given by

$$(a + bi + cj + dk)^{\dagger} = a - bi - cj - dk$$

which reverses the order of multiplication and gives an isomorphism $\mathbb{H} \cong \mathbb{H}^{op}$. Similarly we can consider matrix rings $M_n(k)$ over commutative rings, with involution the transpose $X \mapsto X^T$.

Answer (score 4):

Any group ring $RG$ -- even the group ring of a non-abelian group, which is not commutative -- is isomorphic to it's opposite via the map $g \mapsto g^{-1}$